# K&R "The C Programming Language" exercise 1-13: histograms

Tags: c

> Exercise 1-13. Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of
> words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars
> horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging.

The code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXWLEN 35 /* assuming no word longer than 35 characters will appear in the input */
#define IN 0
#define OUT 1

int main()
{
    int c, len, longest, state, chart[MAXWLEN];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWLEN; ++i)
        chart[i] = 0;

    len = 0; /* length of the current word */
    longest = 0; /* the longest word appearing in the input */
    state = OUT; /* the state of being inside or outside a word */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {       
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        {
            if (state == IN)
                if (longest < ++chart[len-1])
                    longest = chart[len-1];
            state = OUT;
            len = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            state = IN;
            ++len;
        }
    }
    
    char q[2][3] = {"", "   "};

    for (int i = longest; i; --i)
        for (int j = (c = putchar('\n')) - c; j < MAXWLEN; ++j)
            (i <= chart[j]) ? printf(" * ") : printf("%s", q[chart[j] > 0]);
    
    putchar('\n');

    for (int i = 1; i <= MAXWLEN; ++i)
        if(chart[i-1])
            printf("%2d ", i);

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kernighan didn't ask you to "Write a program **which defines several functions**", but implicitly you might view it that way. It's always OK to break out helper functions, such as `getword()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `for (int j = (c = putchar('\n')) - c;` is too clever to be good. You save one line of vertical space by the price of a reviewer's mental effort. Don't do this. Be explicit:

  ```
    putchar('\n');
    for (int j = 0; ....)
  ```

  is much more readable.

  Ditto for

  ```
        (i <= chart[j]) ? printf(" * ") : printf("%s", q[chart[j] > 0]);
  ```
- As said in the comment, more functions please. There are clearly `init_chart`, `fill_chart`, and `print_chart` (every loop deserves to be a function).

  `getword` is also nice to have. It lets you avoid a `IN/OUT` state machine.
- `c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'` is insufficient. At least there is `\v` (vertical tab) and `\f` (formfeed). Prefer `isspace` (don't forget to `#include <ctype.h>`. (I know that it the K&R times it was not available)
- `putchar` may fail. Be prepared.